# Disputing a failed review

Tags: discussion, review-audits

This is the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10604474

The question boils down to:

1. How can I do *this* thing?
2. Here is 100 lines of code, why doesn't it work.

Just because 14 people also want to do what the asker wants, doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: yes i reviewd that but i didn't mean to ask a good question or bad question just this is the site i want to ask my query or question as what site is supposed to be .

Comment: Aren't most questions "how can I do this thing?" 100 lines of code does show some effort which is more than many questions where you just get a raster.